# How to prevent duplicate props inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

In my reactjs App, Slider details are showing from API call. Those are coming from reducer as props. The problem is, I'm getting props multiple times. As a result, my slider display duplicate images and data.is there any solution?.Also i tried `shouldComponentUpdate` as well

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        if (nextProps.slider !== this.props.slider) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
    }

renderSlides(sliderData) {
   console.log("Slider",sliderData);
   return sliderData.data.map(data => {
      return (
         <div key={data.embed_code} className="sliderItem">
           <div>
            <img className="img-fluid" src={data.image_url} alt={'img'}
             <label className="label-free">{data.name}</lable> 
           </div>
         </div>
       );
   });

 }

  render() {
   const { slider } = this.props;
     return (
     <div className="cat-item">
       {this.renderSlides(slider)}
     </div>);
 }
```

my console log as below

[image]

Comment: renderSlides shouln't be a problem and console showing 2 time because your render is calling 2 times, you need to inspect more and findout where the problem is.

Comment: post the code for components calling this. they are probably updating state and thus causing rerender

Comment: As others have said, it's getting re-rendered, that's why it's printing the props twice. Find out why that is, could be because an ancestor is re-rendering, could be cos the store is changing, could be other reasons

Comment: are you seeing double the amount of images? this shouldn't happen just because you received props twice? It will always only render once per update with what ever is in your array, if you are seeing duplicate images, then it's probably something to do with your reducer, please share the reducer code.

Answer (score 0):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        if (JSON.stringify(nextProps.slider) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.slider)) {
            return false;
          }
          return true;
    }
```

`nextProps.slider !== this.props.slider` this is always returns you `false` because the reference is getting change since it creates new array each time. so you can use `stringyfy` an then compare which will help you to stop update when array values are same.